# Windows authentication only for a webpage within solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, handler, windows-authentication, http-redirect

I had a requirement like a solution was there along with 4 projects. Webapp, re-routing Handlers ( which redirect request to my WCF service), Business, Database.
am referencing other projects in my webapp which is having only 1 web page.

Now i need to provide a windows authentication for this web app.

if i implement Windows auth then the existing access from smart devices are not able to connect to the routing handlers.

So i have few Questions which i did some home work and found

[Enabling PUT on IIS 7.5 for an ASHX handler using Windows Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6695587/enabling-put-on-iis-7-5-for-an-ashx-handler-using-windows-authentication)

[How can I grant anonymous access to an httpHandler that uses wildcards in a site that requires authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9978582/how-can-i-grant-anonymous-access-to-an-httphandler-that-uses-wildcards-in-a-site)

So now my doubt is
1. can we bypass the authentication for handlers?
2. can we access it without changing anything in the proxy from smart devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So no responses from any one here. anyway i found a workaround. i guess it might be helpful for others.

I created a loginpage which accepts only windows credentials.  i removed web.config entry to accept only windows authentications.

for the aspx pages what ever the operations am doing. am checking a authentication of the user.

for the remaining pages/handlers am avoiding this cross check so that my service or download request handlers will work without any problem.

Comment: Thanks for your post! Please do not use signatures/taglines in your posts. Your user box counts as your signature, and you can use your profile to post any information about yourself you like. [FAQ on signatures/taglines](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures)